# Auto-rebuild Meteor package when a new file is added?

Tags: meteor, package

I've split my project into multiple packages. However, when I add a new file to the package, I need to edit `package.js`. I've implemented auto-structure using https://gist.github.com/DenisGorbachev/3affd1b90bd18e695184, so I don't have to specify each file manually, but I still need to trigger rebuild by editing `package.js` (e.g. add a newline).

Is it possible to make Meteor pick up new files in packages automatically?